# Bootstrap scrollspy works strange

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollto, zurb-foundation

Hi im Using Bootstrap Scrollspy within the foundation framework.

So far I managed to get scrollspy to work but not like it should.

scrollspy changes the state of the navi correctly but not exactly on the specified div.

The first div container where scrollspy should change the navi works well but then the offset to the following containers increases and at the end scrollspy changes it's state in nomansland and not on top of the div.

When the site is loaded scrollspy displays the last nav entry and not the first??

I guess it is something with percentage based layout. What do you think?

You can find the dev page here:

http://dekonstruktiv.ch/static_sheggendorn/

Thanky for any help

Comment: Was this problem fixed? the page looks ok to me.

Comment: Link to the dev page is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there are some elements being added to the page after scrollspy gets initialized.  You will need to call refresh after everything is loaded.

```js
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
    var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
});
```

Comment: Hmm. Where do I have to put this refresh snippet? I put it right before the scrollspy call. but nothing happens.

Comment: It should go after scrollspy call.  Or better yet, if some other plugins are loading content on the page, you can put it in a callback function after the content is loaded.

Comment: I found the solution: I used the jquery call `$('#avbar').scrollspy()` from the bootstrap docs in combination with `<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navigation" data-offset="60">` from the example page. That dosn't make jQuery very happy. Now it works al fine. Thanks @HaiNguyen for your suggestion.